# How to estimate the time taken for a job to complete?

Tags: education, estimation

I have a job x which copies file y with data size of 200GB from one disk to another. I would like to estimate an accurate time it takes for the job to complete from current time. This requires basic maths to solve but i am weak in maths. Is there any method or formula to calculate this efficiently?

```
job x throughput rate- 20MB/sec
Total data size to be copied - 200GB
```

Comment: $\frac{200GB}{20\frac{MB}{s}} = 10000s$ is the full time.

Comment: I think you should post your question oni https://stackoverflow.com, where you should get some answers that help you with the realities of this type of estimation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$20MB/s=0.02GB/s$$
$$T=\frac{200GB}{0.02GB/s}=10,000s\approx 2.8\text{hours}$$
The first line is due to the conversion from mega($10^6)$ to giga($10^9$) then the second line you can think of as similar to:
$$\text{speed}=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$$
rearranged. Hope this helps

---

One thing to note- whilst this isn't a comp sci forum- data transfer rates vary as some data is "harder" to copy than others, as well as things like internet speed affecting download. You also have to allow time for the specific file formatting system to make the directories required

Comment: +1: the OP should ask this question on https://stackoverflow.com.